# RavenDB query child collection polymorphism

Tags: c#, ravendb, nosql

I have a document in RavenDB that contains a child collection. The child collection contains the following base type.

```
public class Section
{
    public string BackgroundColor { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string DesktopBackgroundImageUrl { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public string MobileBackgroundImageUrl { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public string TextColor { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public SectionType Type { get; set; }
}
```

There are a few derived classes from this type, one of which being this.

```
public class OfferSection : Section
{
    public IEnumerable<Merchant> Merchants { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I need to query this child collection and get the documents that contain the derived type and then query it's values.

This is where I've got to so far, however because it's using the base type, the `Merchants` property doesn't exist

```
public class Hubs_ByMerchantId : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Hub>
{
    public Hubs_ByMerchantId()
    {
        Map = hubs => from hub in hubs
            select new
            {
                Sections_Merchants_Id = hub.Sections.Where(x => x.Type == SectionType.Offer).SelectMany(x => x.Merchants.Select(y => y.Id))
            };
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of messing about the way I got this to work was by casting it inside the select. This worked because we already have a type enum saved against the section so it's easy enough to do the cast.

```
public class Hubs_ByMerchantId : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Hub>
{
    public Hubs_ByMerchantId()
    {
        Map = hubs => hubs.SelectMany(x => (IEnumerable<OfferSection>)x.Sections).Where(x => x.Type == SectionType.Offer).Select(x => new
        {
            Sections_Merchants_Id = x.Merchants.Select(y => y.Id)
        });
    }
}
```

This probably isn't the best solution but it was the only thing that worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.OfType<Type>` to get what ypou want:

```
hub.Sections.OfType<OfferSection>().SelectMany(x => x.Merchants.Select(y => y.Id));
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Raven returns an error saying that it can't understand `OfType()`

Comment: It works for me, if I have `Hub` class, which contains property `public IEnumerable<Section> Sections { get; set; }` Please add information about what is hub in your code.

Comment: The code above is what I have. OfType() works on normal objects, however I can't use this inside a Raven index because Raven throws an error saying that it doesn't understand what to do with OfType()